# Combine sprite bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, bounding-box

I'm trying to make a collider the size of the bounding box of the sprites.

What I have is a `GameObject` with three sprites. I want to use only one collider to cover the whole GameObject, so I tried taking the middle sprite's `Bounds` and use the `Encapsulate` method from the [Bounds class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html) to increase the size of the bounds and then give that size to the collider.

The collider comes as right size if I only pass in the *sprite 2* bounds. But if I `Encapsulate` the *first and third sprites* the collider's size becomes odd.

[image]

Code:

```
Bounds spriteTwoBounds = parentGO.GetBounds(spriteTwo);

foreach (Transform t in parentGO.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
{
    if (t.HasSpriteRenderer())
    {
        spriteTwoBounds.Encapsulate(t.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds);
    }
}
parentGO.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = spriteTwoBounds.size;
```

Comment: Could you define what happens when you say 'size becomes odd'?

Comment: @MicroVirus Depending on the sprites sizes and shapes it becomes anything from huge to very small.

Comment: Have you stepped through the relevant code with the debugger to see what values the bounding box takes? At what point doesn't it work as expected? The size member should always grow if Encapsulate is used; do you observe this behaviour? Other than these generic pointers, I'm going to take a wild guess here: are you modifying a Bounds variable somewhere and not reassigning it to the member it was taken from (as I take it Bounds is a struct, so the variable holds a copy and not the original).